# Limit number of rows added to 10 in 'Add Row' function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an "Add Row" function in java script.  How do I limit the number of rows added to no more then 10 rows? Here is my code. Thanks for the help!

```
$(document).on('click', '#addAddOnDay', function() {
    var rowCount = $('#addOnDay tr').length + 1;
    var rowClass = (rowCount % 2 != 0) ? 'rowOdd' : 'rowEven';
    $('#addOnDay').append('<tr class="'+ rowClass +'"> \
<td align="center"><input type="text" class="text" style="width: 99%;" /></td> \
<td align="center"><input type="radio" name="4a_1"> <label>Yes</label> &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="4a_1" checked> <label>No</label></td> \
<td align="center">20000 or 95%</td> \
<td align="center" class="rollUpDisplay">1</td> \
</tr>');
});
```

Comment: You already have the `rowCount`, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click','#addAddOnDay',function(){

                var rowCount = $('#addOnDay tr').length; // current number of rows
                if(rowCount >= 10) {
                        return ;
                        }
   // Rest of the code....

                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Encase it in an extra condition

```
if( $('#addOnDay ').find('tr').length < 10) {

    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Chan you show the code that you are trying out with.. Also check for any errors in the console section

Answer (score 0):

You could add a check for how many rows already exist at the beginning of your function, and bail out if it's at or greater than 10:

```
if ($('#addOnDay tr').length >= 10)
    return;
```

Actually, since you already check the count to do the zebra-striping, just add an additional check:

```
$(document).on('click','#addAddOnDay',function(){
    var rowCount = $('#addOnDay tr').length;
    if (rowCount >= 10)
        return false;
    var rowClass = (rowCount + 1) % 2 == 0 ? 'rowEven' : 'rowOdd';
    ...
});
```

Comment: I am using your code but, I need to make rowCount >= 12 to get only 10 rows, it seems to be off by 2 no matter what I make the number

Comment: Can you add to your post the markup for the `<table>` you're starting with?